# How to instantiate autowired services in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, testing, symfony4

I want to instantiate OrderAbstraction service which requires entity manager in constructor in a test case.

```
class OrderAbstraction
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried to autowire OrderAbstractionTest and give a OrderAbstraction and entity manager as parameter.

```
class OrderAbstractionTest extends TestCase
{
// tried with constructor and without it
    public function testDays(){
        $order = new OrderAbstraction();
        $order->dateFrom(new \DateTime('2019-08-20 14:00'));
        $order->dateTo(new \DateTime('2019-08-28 14:00'));

        $days = $order->days();
        $this->assertEquals(8, $days);
    }
}
```

my service.yaml, autowire set to true

```
    App\Service\OrderAbstraction\:
        resource: '../src/Service/OrderAbstraction.php'
        arguments: 
            $em: '@Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'

    App\Test\OrderAbstraction\:
        resource: '../tests/OrderAbstractionTest.php'
        arguments: 
            $em : '@Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'
```

I keep getting something like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function App\Test\OrderAbstractionTest::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /var/www/html/autocom/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php
>   on line 476 and exactly 1 expected in
>   /var/www/html/autocom/tests/OrderAbstractionTest.php:13

Would be great to know how to instantiate services like OrderAbstraction to other services, tests. Because most of the I do something like this in controllers:

```
$order = new OrderAbstraction($this->em);
```

Comment: Can you show us your TestSuite.php, especially around line 476

Comment: $constructor = $theClass->getConstructor();

        if ($constructor !== null) {
            $parameters = $constructor->getParameters();

            // TestCase() or TestCase($name)
            if (\count($parameters) < 2) {
                $test = new $className;
            } // TestCase($name, $data)
            else {
                try {
                    $data = \PHPUnit\Util\Test::getProvidedData(
                        $className,
                        $name
                    );
                } catch (IncompleteTestError $e)
Sorry can't format text

Comment: I also get error
1) App\Test\OrderAbstractionTest::testDays
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Service\OrderAbstraction::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/autocom/tests/OrderAbstractionTest.php on line 13 and exactly 1 expected

/var/www/html/autocom/src/Service/OrderAbstraction.php:173
/var/www/html/autocom/tests/OrderAbstractionTest.php:13

Comment: Have you tried dumping $this->em when you try to instantiate OrderAbstraction to see if it's really an EM ?

Comment: I believe I can't dump in unit test, but I think $this->em is a null.
My unit test doesn't receive @doctrine.orm.entity_manager from service.yaml, I'll try to work on that.
But I thought It should be possible to instantiate a service without providing an entity manager.

Comment: You are trying to create an OrderAbstraction by passing an EM, if it's null, it's not surprising you are gonna have a problem.

Comment: Ok, should I autowire entity manager in unit test? I thought autowiring OrderAbstraction should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What end up working for me is php unit mock, my code now looks like this:

```
    public function testDays(){
        $em = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

        $order = new OrderAbstraction($em);
        $order->dateFrom(new \DateTime('2019-08-20 14:00'));
        $order->dateTo(new \DateTime('2019-08-28 14:00'));

        $days = $order->days();
        $this->assertEquals(8, $days);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need anything in the services.yml if autowire is set to true. Replace EntityManager by EntityManagerInterface in your **OrderAbstraction.php** to get an instance of EntityManager being automatically injected when your service is autowired.

**OrderAbstraction.php**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class OrderAbstraction {

  /**
   * @var EntityManager
   */
  private $em;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
    ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

As this would work as expected in a basic controller, you can't use the constructor of your unit test class to inject your service. According to Symfony's [blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing) :

> In Symfony 4.1, tests allow fetching private services by default.
>   In practice, tests based on WebTestCase and KernelTestCase now access to a special container via the static::$container property that allows fetching non-removed private services:

**OrderAbstractionTest.php**

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use App\Service\OrderAbstraction;

class OrderAbstractionTest extends WebTestCase {

  /**
   * @var OrderAbstraction
   */
  private $order;

  public function testDays() {
    self::bootKernel();
    $this->order = static::$container->get(OrderAbstraction::class);

    $this->order->dateFrom(new \DateTime('2019-08-20 14:00'));
    $this->order->dateTo(new \DateTime('2019-08-28 14:00'));

    $days = $this->order->days();
  }
}
```

Tested and working fine on Symfony 4.3
See [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940243/11881259) for more info about Symfony 3.4 and 4.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get this error: 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Test\OrderAbstractionTest::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/autocom/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.5/src/Framework/TestSuite.php on line 476 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/html/autocom/tests/OrderAbstractionTest.php:17

Comment: This solution works, you just forgot to add 

        $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
thank your for your help!